# gcloud PHP doesn't connect to sql

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to set up a PHP file and MySQL server on gcloud to be used by an IoT device with onboard HTML/JS/CSS but I can't get my PHP (on app engine) to properly connect to the MySQL. (I'm quite new to gcloud)

I have some code to check for connection errors but it doesn't throw any errors, even if I pass the wrong password.

Here is my PHP, it should set up the connection and insert some test data, but I always get the "Error inserting data..." echo with a blank $mysqli->error.

```
<?php
    $host = getenv("MYSQL_HOST");
    $user = getenv("MYSQL_USER");
    $pass = getenv("MYSQL_PASSWORD");
    $db = getenv("MYSQL_DB");
    $port = getenv("MYSQL_PORT");
    $socket = getenv("MYSQL_SOCKET");

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port, $socket);

    // Check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

    $date = '2020-05-12 15:47:01';
    $value = 18.2;
    $unit = "DegC";
    $label = "Temperature 1 (TEST VALS)";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Data(data_id, date, value, unit, label)
    VALUES(NULL, $date, $value, $unit, $label);";

    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Data inserted";
    } else {
        echo "Error inserting data: " . $mysqli->error;
    }

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Here is the app.yaml I have.

```
runtime: php72

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: project:location:instance-name

env_variables:
  MYSQL_HOST: localhost
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345
  MYSQL_DB: dbname
  MYSQL_PORT: NULL
  MYSQL_SOCKET: /cloudsql/project:location:instance-name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the variables below instead of the ones you are using, as specified in the [GCP samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php72/cloudsql#setup):

```
CLOUDSQL_USER: USER
CLOUDSQL_PASSWORD: PASSWORD
CLOUDSQL_DSN: "mysql:dbname=DATABASE;unix_socket=/cloudsql/CONNECTION_NAME"
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the connection is working now when I use ```getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS)``` and I'm getting the 'Data inserted' success message but the new values aren't there when I check in cloud shell.

```$sql = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Data(data_id, date, value, unit, label) VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
    $sql->execute([$date, $value, $unit, $label]);```
That's how I'm inserting now. (Sorry about the formatting)

Comment: Try [binding the parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and logging the stmt value before executing it to see that all the values are correct.